# Entity is not api accessible

Tags: permissions, salesforce

I am trying to check the *UserLicense* Object's permissions like below and getting the "Entity is not api accessible" error.

**Schema.sObjectType.UserLicense.isAccessible()**

Please help me with any resolution.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

`UserLicense` is a system object. It's not permissionable at all. You don't need to check CRUD or FLS permissions on `UserLicense` (you can't perform any DML or apply Profile permissions on it anyway).

Comment: SELECT Profile.UserLicense.Name FROM User WHERE IsActive = true GROUP BY Profile.UserLicense.Name
I am checking CRUD permission for this query because I am getting the below error: 
No such relation 'UserLicense' on entity 'Profile'.
Please suggest me any workaround for this.

Comment: I believe that's one of the weird places in the schema where you cannot traverse the relationship and have to make two queries.

Comment: How do I need to query this?
SELECT Profile.UserLicense.Name FROM User WHERE IsActive = true GROUP BY Profile.UserLicense.Name